# how to convert html select to bootstrap select?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, render, html-select, bootstrap-select

I'm using Bootstrap in my web application and new to it. And I have a question about how to convert a normal html select to a bootstrap select.

I need to populate a div with a bootstrap select using ajax after the entire page has been rendered, but the select I returned is a normal html select. I tried to call render, refresh method of selectPicker to render it as bootstrap select, but it didn't work.[See my normal html select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Ral.png)

Very appreciate if anyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: which plugin are you using to convert normal select to bootstrap select?

Comment: it's bootstrap-select.js.

Comment: Can you confirm?? because different plugins have different synta to initialize it

Comment: yes, it's bootstrap-select.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this script after you append your select element HTML in your ajax call.

```
$('#form-SchemeUUID').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info'  
});
```

Also make sure the CSS and Js files of the plugin is added into the page.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I took the wrong id. $('#form-SchemeUUID').selectpicker(''refresh) also works well.